# Cannot Bind to asp:Dropdownlist in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, I cannot bind to an asp:Dropdownlist inside a Modal, and I can't figure out what I am missing.  If I move the dropdownlist outside of the Modal, that data binds perfectly, but inside the Modal, the dropdownlist is always blank.  Can someone please tell me what I am missing here:

Here is the Modal:

```
    <div id="copyEmployeeModal" class="md-modal colored-header md-effect-9 prmiary">
    <div class="md-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal3" aria-hidden="true" class="close md-close" onclick="return CloseModal();"><i class="icon s7-close"></i></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">
                <asp:Label ID="lblcopyEmployeeModalTitle" runat="server" Text="Copy Employee Permissions"></asp:Label>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form" style="padding: 0px!important;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNonGroupEmployees" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code to bind the dropdownlist:

```
 ddlNonGroupEmployees.DataSource = GetNonGroupEmployees();
 ddlNonGroupEmployees.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
 ddlNonGroupEmployees.DataValueField = "EmployeeId";
 ddlNonGroupEmployees.DataBind();
```

I know the above code has data, and as I said if I move the dropdownlist out of the modal and place it on the page, the data binds to the dropdownlist with no issues.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sry if this is way off, i haven't checked this, but any chance the modal is hidden or not displayed by css before it's used (unfindable)? [and, typo in first line: `prmiary`.]

Comment: The modal is hidden to begin with.  Perhaps that is the issue?  If so, how do I  bind to it.  It needs to be hidden at first.

Comment: When is the binding code called?

Comment: Binding is done on a SelectedIndex change on a dropdown on the page.

Comment: You are definitely, correct.  If I call the binding on postback, the dropdownlist populates with no problem.